# Taking data from form with Ajax and then inserting into DB using PHP (PDO connection)

Tags: php, sql, ajax, pdo

I am trying to get data from form, write with AJAX 'Thanks for your question' and send data to php script, and then with PHP insert data into database and send an email.My problem is that it always inserts empty rows into database. Do you have any advice?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQzkJ.jpg)
forma -  kontakt.php

```
<form>
              <input type="text" name="ime" id="ime" placeholder="Ime" />
              <input type="text" name="prezime" id="prezime" placeholder="Prezime" />
               <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
               <textarea type="text" style="width:100%; height:180px" name="poruka" id="poruka" placeholder="Poruka"></textarea>

               <button class="graybtn" onclick="return formamsg1()">Pošalji</button><br><br>
               <div id="placefortable">
                </div><br><br>

        </form>
```

ajax - formamsg1

```
  function formamsg1(){
          var ime = document.getElementById("ime").value;
          var prezime = document.getElementById("prezime").value;
          var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
          var poruka = document.getElementById("poruka").value;
          var dataString = "ime="+encodeURIComponent(ime)+"&prezime="+encodeURIComponent(prezime)+"&email="+encodeURIComponent(email)+"&poruka="+encodeURIComponent(poruka);
        $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url: "obavestenje.php",
              cashe: false,
              data: dataString,
              success: function(data){
                  //window.alert(data);
                  document.getElementById("placefortable").innerHTML = data;
              },
              error: function (req, status, err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
            }
          })
          return false;
```

}

PHP - obavestenje.php

```
require_once 'include/db.php';
$allowed_params = allowed_post_params(['ime', 'prezime', 'email', 'poruka', 'submit']);
// niz sadrzi dozvoljene maksimalne duzine za sva polja
$fields_lengths = ['ime' => 64, 'prezime' => 256, 'email'=>256, 'poruka' => 256];


// provera da li su polja odgovoarajuce duzine
foreach ($fields_lengths as $field => $length) {
if (!has_length($_POST[$field], ['min' => 0, 'max' => $length])) {
    header('Location: greska.html');
    die();
}
}

try {

// Priprema upita za unos podataka u bazu
$prep = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO kontakt_forma (ime, prezime, email, poruka) VALUES(:ime, :prezime, :email, :poruka)");
$prep->bindParam(':ime', $ime);
$prep->bindParam(':prezime', $prezime); 
$prep->bindParam(':email', $email);
$prep->bindParam(':poruka', $poruka);

$ime = isset($allowed_params['ime']) ? $allowed_params['ime'] : "";
$prezime = isset($allowed_params['prezime']) ? $allowed_params['prezime'] : "";
$email = isset($allowed_params['email']) ? $allowed_params['email'] : "";
$poruka = isset($allowed_params['poruka']) ? $allowed_params['poruka'] : "";    

// izvrsavanja upita
$rez = $prep->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'greska kod upita';

}
// Ukoliko je upis u bazu uspesan, salje se mejl korisnuku i klijentu o uspesnoj prijavi
if ($rez) {

$emailod = "$email";
$email_to = 'milicapavlovic0312@gmail.com'; // treba da bude  'organictest@organic.milica-pavlovic.com';
$subject = "samo organsko";
$headers = "From: $emailod\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$email_message = "Kontakt forma " . "<br>";

$email_message .= "Ime: $ime " . "<br>";
$email_message .= "Prezime: $prezime " . "<br>";
$email_message .= "Poruka: $poruka " . "<br>";

if (mail($email_to, $subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
$htmltable = "Hvala na postavljenom pitanju. Ocekujte odgovor u roku od 24h.";
echo $htmltable;
} else {
echo 'greska kod slanja mail f';
die();
}   
} else {
echo 'greska kod emaila-dva';
die();
```

}

Comment: Suggestion; Give your `<form>` an id and just do `data: $('#theFormId').serialize(),` instead of fetching all the values and building your own string.

Comment: Where is `$allowed_params` defined?

Comment: You're trying to bind params before you defined them.

Comment: Also, if you add a proper submit button to the form and attach your function to the submit event of the form you will also be able to capture the form data when someone submits it by pressing enter.

Comment: Somehow when I add $allowed_params it doesnt work at all.

Comment: @MilicaPavlovic Well, what does the `allowed_post_params()` function do? And is it available in obavestenje.php?

Comment: Thank you all. It was my mistake, I didnt include in project functions.php. Now it is resolved

Answer (score 0):

You should send your data as Object not as String. Try changing JavaScript and PHP:

JavaScript File

```
  function formamsg1(){
          var ime = document.getElementById("ime").value;
          var prezime = document.getElementById("prezime").value;
          var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
          var poruka = document.getElementById("poruka").value;
          var data = {
              "ime" : ime,
              "prezime" : prezime,
              "email" : email,
              "poruka" : poruka
          } 

        $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url: "obavestenje.php",
              cashe: false,
              data: data,
              success: function(data){
                  //window.alert(data);
                  document.getElementById("placefortable").innerHTML = data;
              },
              error: function (req, status, err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
            }
          })
          return false;
```

PHP File

```
require_once 'include/db.php';


try {

$ime = isset($_POST['ime']) ? $_POST['ime'] : "";
$prezime = isset($_POST['prezime']) ? $_POST['prezime'] : "";
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
$poruka = isset($_POST['poruka']) ? $_POST['poruka'] : ""; 

// Priprema upita za unos podataka u bazu
$prep = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO kontakt_forma (ime, prezime, email, poruka) VALUES(:ime, :prezime, :email, :poruka)");
$prep->bindParam(':ime', $ime);
$prep->bindParam(':prezime', $prezime); 
$prep->bindParam(':email', $email);
$prep->bindParam(':poruka', $poruka);


// izvrsavanja upita
$rez = $prep->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'greska kod upita';

}
// Ukoliko je upis u bazu uspesan, salje se mejl korisnuku i klijentu o uspesnoj prijavi
if ($rez) {

$emailod = "$email";
$email_to = 'milicapavlovic0312@gmail.com'; // treba da bude  'organictest@organic.milica-pavlovic.com';
$subject = "samo organsko";
$headers = "From: $emailod\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$email_message = "Kontakt forma " . "<br>";

$email_message .= "Ime: $ime " . "<br>";
$email_message .= "Prezime: $prezime " . "<br>";
$email_message .= "Poruka: $poruka " . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Changing how the data is passed to the `$.ajax` function actually does not change how this data is sent to the server. Though there are more elegant methods than OP used in his code (see the comments).

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the Params before actually seeing if they have been posted.

And since all the data is wrapped in ime you won't be easily able to retrieve what is sent.

```
    data: {
inputEmail: email,
inputPoruka: poruka
},
```

Ect